# How to call 2 sequential functions in clojure?

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm trying to do exercise 20 on https://iloveponies.github.io/120-hour-epic-sax-marathon/recursion.html. Here's my code:

```
(defn my-frequencies-helper [freqs a-seq]
  (let [first-elem (first a-seq)
        rest-of-seq (rest a-seq)]
    (if (nil? first-elem)
      freqs
      (if (contains? freqs first-elem)
        (assoc freqs first-elem (inc (get freqs first-elem)))
        (assoc freqs first-elem 1)))))

(defn my-frequencies [a-seq]
  (my-frequencies-helper {} a-seq))
```

The problem is that this is not recursive. Somehow I need to add the following line into `my-frequencies-helper` after updating the `freqs` map:

```
(my-frequencies-helper freqs rest-of-seq)
```

Since it isn't dependent on a branch of an `if` function, I can't see how to do it without adding too many parameters to the `if` functions. I.e. it doesn't fit a `cond` or `if` because it's a step I want to call after doing another, functionally unrelated step.

I've probably got it wrong, but imperatively I just want to recursively call `my-frequencies-helper` after updating the map, i.e. in python something like:

```
freqs[first-elem] = freqs[first-elem] + 1
my-frequencies-helper(freqs, rest-of-seq)          # just another step to execute
```

How can I lever this into my code (or more likely, what would be another simple way to approach this)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can simplify this code quite a bit with the help of destructuring:

```
(defn my-frequencies-helper
  [freqs [first-elem & rest-of-seq :as a-seq]]
    (if (empty? a-seq)
      freqs
      (let [updated-freqs (if (contains? freqs first-elem)
                            (assoc freqs first-elem (inc (get freqs first-elem)))
                            (assoc freqs first-elem 1))]
        (my-frequencies-helper updated-freqs rest-of-seq))))
```

Furthermore there is a common idiom for

```
(if (contains? freqs first-elem)
  (assoc freqs first-elem (inc (get freqs first-elem)))
  (assoc freqs first-elem 1))
```

The following is equivalent, as long as you would not store nil in the place of one of the numbers:

```
(update-in freqs [first-elem] (fnil inc 0))
```

This leaves us with the following simplified function:

```
(defn my-frequencies-helper
  [freqs [first-elem & rest-of-seq :as a-seq]]
    (if (empty? a-seq)
      freqs
      (my-frequencies-helper (update-in freqs [first-elem] (fnil inc 0)) rest-of-seq)))
```

Comment: @jbrown You can also turn the `if` expression inside out and absorb it in a `get`: `(assoc freqs first-elem (inc (get freqs first-elem 0)))`. Though clumsier, this has the advantage of dealing properly with false/nil elements. But you then have to change your not-empty test to `(if (seq a-seq) ... )`. I think @noisesmith had this in mind, since `a-seq` is not used.

Comment: Checking `(nil? first-elem)` is really bad, because you can't process sequences that contain `nil` in them.

Comment: @amalloy so what should I use instead to determine if I've reached the base case?

Comment: `(empty? a-seq)` would be better, making that edit now

Answer (score 0):

For each item in the list, you'd want to look up in the result dictionary, to see if that item is already there, if so, you'd save it +1, if not, just store 1 in that dictionary.

with this you could solve it with a simple recursion, or use reduce.

Spoiler:

> `(defn my-frequencies [x] (reduce(fn[t n](assoc t n (inc(get t n 0)))) {} x))`

Comment: This is essentially how [core `frequencies`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/028af0e0b271aa558ea44780e5d951f4932c7842/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6617) works.